# Linear Program to solve NP-hard problems

Tags: complexity-theory, linear-programming

I'm pretty new to the realm of LP, and this question has been bothering me for a long time. I know that Simplex algorithm takes exponential time in the worst case but practical on average, but Ellipsoid can solve LP with exponential number of constraints in polynomial time in the worst case. Then my question is, when you try to formulate NP-hard problems into LP, shouldn't Ellipsoid algorithm be able to solve them in poly-time? Do LP-programmable NP-hard problems always imply exponential number of variables and constraints?

Comment: There is no way to reduce an NP-hard problem to Linear Programming. Remember, Simplex Method and Ellipsoid Algorithm apply to Linear Programs with rational unknowns. Things get different for Linear Programs with Integral unknowns where NP-hard problems live.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov isn't it still possible to formulate an LP in a theoretical sense? (although we wouldn't be able to run it on simplex or ellipsoid algorithm) I have seen my professor demonstrating an LP formulation of hitting set problem.

Comment: You must distinguish Linear Programming in Rationals and Integer Linear Programming. A reduction of Hitting Set was probably an [Integer Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Integer_linear_program_formulation) problem. If you treat it as an LP problem in Rationals you would get nonsensical solutions with fractional portions of sets.

Comment: It was not Integer Linear Programming, I swear. I'm so eager to show what my professor wrote. Do you mind if I send it to you via email?

Comment: Or, check the comment section in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471543/vertex-cover-without-integer-programming/2471608?noredirect=1#comment5106775_2471608. I wrote prof's steps in a bit sketchy way, but the idea is there.

Comment: We could continue over at Math.SE or proceed here. You might notice that the reduction that you propose is very similar to the one in the Wikipedia article that I linked to above. Now suppose that the Rational LP problem gives you a solution with fractional numbers and the value of optimal cost function equals 4.75. It gives absolutely no information as to whether there exists a hitting set with 5, 6 or in fact any number of vertices greater than that. It does say though that no solution with cost function equal 4 or less exists.

Comment: So if my assignment question asks to formulate LP for minimum vertex cover problem, does it mean that I have to relax the integer constraint?

Comment: I would think that your professor implicitly assumes Integer Linear Programming when he talks about LP in this context. So I would try to produce an integer linear programming formulation (or in fact 0-1) for this assignment.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but since the prof hasn't introduced us with LIP, I think we still have to formulate it as LP. As for the hitting set problem, he didn't use LIP. Do you think, the reduction he used for hitting set problem, could possibly be formulated in a way such that it always returns an optimal vector whose sum of entries must be integer, although fractional value seems to be possible, but it actually isn't?

Comment: You should definitely try to clarify any misunderstanding with your professor or a TA, but the reduction from Hitting Set to a linear optimization problem is not correct without the integrality constraint on the variables. If you had slides or lecture notes it would be easier to figure out precisely what is going on.

Comment: ```As for the hitting set problem, he didn't use LIP. Do you think, the reduction he used for hitting set problem, could possibly be formulated in a way such that it always returns an optimal vector whose sum of entries must be integer, although fractional value seems to be possible, but it actually isn't?``` If P/=NP; assuming a sub-exponential number of variables/constraints: No! (no need to check the classic theory of total unimodularity; this follows from complexity-theory), LP will not help for any NP-hard problem (theory-wise); but might be a component of an heuristic algorithm (MIP)